# How to reconnect after WIFI connection is lost and restored later in Python urllib

Tags: python, html, urllib, urllib2

I'm trying to make a python program that checks the title of a website every 2 seconds. My program works
fine when the connection is good. But when I lose the wifi connection, the python program sometimes do print "connection lost...." and starts printing the title of a website after wifi connection is restored.

But sometimes when the wifi connection is lost and the program doesn't print "connection lost...", it doesn't show title even after the connection is restored as if the program has hanged and does nothing. Not sure how I fix this.

```
import urllib.request

notFound = True
while(notFound):
    try:
        version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
        URL = "https://www.google.com/"
        req = urllib.request.Request(url = URL, data=None, headers={'User-Agent': version})
        f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        webpage = str(f.read())
        code = f.code
        print(code)
        title = find_between_r(webpage,titleChar[0],titleChar[1]) #prints title of webpage
        print(title)
    except urllib.request.URLError as e:
        print("connection lost...")
        time.sleep(2)
```

So I'm trying to figure out a way how I can write this program so even when I lose my connection and reconnect again it starts working like how did before it lost connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
f = urllib.request.urlopen(req, timeout=10)
```

This will force a 10 second timeout and throw an error if it passes 10 seconds.

Let me know if this fixed your issue or if the problem still persists.

Comment: Problem still exist, this time it waits for few seconds and then closes the program. I want the program to basically print "Connection lost..." and to start printing title of webpage after the connection is back